# How to force the treeview's scrollbar to appear / expand?

Tags: c#, winforms

Assume that treeview's Scrollable Property has been set to true correctly.
As the scrollbar appears only when the treenodes is out of the visible area. However, I want it to always showing a blank area below the buttom treenode(where treeViewHitTestInfo.Location == none), while the scrollbar will only expand pettily to show all the treenode. Sometimes, the lowest treenode(whose index is largest at root) only show about 40% of the label in the treeview, and EnsureVisible() don't work at all.

I tried SetScrollRange() in user32.dll to change the scrollbar's height. However, it doesn't work well. It seems that the treeview's "client area" is settled by the system's caculation using my nodes's height and unchangable for me.

Is there a way to force it to expand?